# About comparing standard scores

Tags: statistical-significance, p-value

I have time-series data, from which I would like to detect anomalies. I have Z-scored the time-series, and there is two points which clearly deviate from the baseline. Their Z-scores are 3 and 6, respectively. So, I can say they differ significantly from the baseline. Can I also say that the two anomalies themselves differ significantly, given their different Z-scores? Needless to say I'm new to statistics...

Comment: You have identified two data points that appear anomalous. There is no gain to adding the further word "significant", as you haven't carried out a significance test. Significance tests are for tests of hypotheses about parameters. It's much more fruitful to think about the anomalous points: can you be sure that they don't represent measurement or calculation errors? can something be identified about the times or circumstances in which they occurred that makes them less surprising?

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't recommend making that claim for the following reasons:

1) Two data points cannot be compared with statistical test like t-test, which involve both mean and variance. If you have a 3 and a 6, then 6 is bigger. There is no inference here, and hence no need to worry about statistical significance.

2) Now that the statistical significance is out of the window, what about practical significance? It turned out it's difficult to judge by just looking at the z-score.

[image]

The top row shows the histogram of x1 and x2, where x1 has a higher variability. Both distribution have two outliers at the right. Notice that the absolute deviation is about 6 in x1, but only about 3 in x2.

The bottom row shows the standardized version of them (aka in z-score). Notice that both outliers now got a z-score of 6. If we just look at the z-score, and try to make any judgment about the difference between the outliers without the context of the rest of the distribution, it wouldn't mean too much. In x1, the difference between the top two outlier is 3 unit; in x2, it's 1.5 unit.

In a nutshell, an outlier is an outlier only because the rest of the samples make it so. If you would like to elaborate more on the two numbers, it'd perhaps help your audience to understand the magnitude if you also provide the descriptive data in the original scale as well.

And I also agree with Nick's comment that instead of worrying if 6 is bigger than 3, it'd be more important to clarify if they are legitimate, and what might have made them so extreme.

Answer (score 0):

If your z-scores are 3 and 6, then they are 3 and 6 standard deviations away from the mean, respectively.  By basically every statistical test, these are significantly different from the mean z-score, which is 0. Another way to view this is that  they are both well above the 99th percentile, whereas a Z-score of 0 is at the 50th percentile.   The 3 and the 6 are also 3 sd's away from each other, so yes they would be significantly different from each other too.